# Why i get runtime error when i try to use erase function of a stl vector of class elements?

Tags: c++, class, vector, runtime-error, erase

I have a class Player:

```
class Player
{
    public:
        int pos,money;
        float x,z,y;
        string name;
        Model pion,banner;
}
```

and a class Model

```
class Model
{
    public:
        vector<coordinate>vertex;
        vector<uv>textureCoordinates;
        vector<coordinate>normals;
        vector<face>faces;
        vector<material>materials;
}
```

The struct coordinate,uv,face and materials have only float and int variables in them so dont worry.
I also have a

```
vector<Player>player;
```

At some point in my program i try to do

```
int currentPlayer=something;
player.erase(player.begin()+currentPlayer);
```

When i do that my program stops and gives me an error:

```
Proces returned -1073741819 <0x0000005>
```

What am i doing wrong?How should i build my destructor?

Comment: Please say you simplified-out setting currentPlayer to something before that call to `erase`. Uninitialized value could try to take that vector just about anywhere.

Comment: I did ,thats not the problem.

Comment: As you can see above,my member variables are stl vectors.i dont use any other types of data,like pointers.so i didnt feel the need to create a copy constructor.

Comment: Does execution even reach Player's destructor? Debugger or an print statement can tell you that easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::advance(iterator, n) to advance your iterator to n position and erase it.

Comment: But why am i geting that error exacly?I would like to know

Comment: is your currentPlayer variable initialized in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.It looks like when i had only 1 player left my code didnt worked anymore because somewhere in my code i did

```
currentPlayer++;
currentPlayer%=player.size();
```

and since player.size() was equal to 1 that caused my problems down the line.Ty for help anyway.